# PowerShell command not getting executed using java Process class. While all other commands are working fine

Tags: java, powershell

I am trying to execute below command using java Process class but it's not giving me any response or neither its effecting which it should do.

But when I am executing the command directly on PowerShell its working fine only it's not working using java code. I have tried other PowerShell commands, and all are working fine accept this one.

It's a command to disable indexing of a drive.

Output its only printing the command and in response of isAlive() method call it replies with false.

Command: `powershell.exe Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveLetter='I:'" | Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{IndexingEnabled=$False}`

> isAlive : false

There is nothing more in the code I am just calling this method from my main class that's it like `classObject.disableIndexing("D")`

Note I am executing the same using admin rights only.
Please help.

```
public String disableIndexing(String driveLetter) {
        
    String returnVal="";
    String command = "powershell.exe Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter \"DriveLetter='"+driveLetter+":'\" | Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{IndexingEnabled=$False} ";
    try {   
        System.out.println(command);
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        String line1="";
        String line="";
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line1 = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line1);
            if(!line1.isEmpty())
            System.err.println(line1);
        }
        System.out.println(p.isAlive());
        if(p.exitValue()==0) {
            returnVal="Indexing changed Successfully";
                }else {
            returnVal="Your Drive is Not Responding Try After Some Time";
            }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            
    }
    return returnVal;
        
}
```

Comment: I tried that as well. But same response.

Comment: *I tried that as well. But same response* Please edit your question to show that code you tried. Also call `inheritIO` on the builder

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is likely that `|` is interpreted by the default shell (eg. cmd.exe) before being passed to `powershell.exe`.

To work around this, use the `-EncodedCommand` command line switch to safely pass the command to `powershell.exe`:

```
public String disableIndexing(String driveLetter) {
    String driveLetter = "D";
    String powerShellCommand = "Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter \"DriveLetter='" + driveLetter + ":'\" | Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{IndexingEnabled=$False}";

    // Base64-encode the UTF16LE representation of the command
    byte[] powerShellBytes = powerShellCommand.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
    String encodedCmd = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(powerShellBytes));

    String command = "powershell.exe -EncodedCommand " + encodedCmd;

    try {
        // proceed the same as before ...
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, Thanks for quick reply. I tried as you suggested with encoding request but got the same 'no response' output. Also, index didn't disable Its same as before.

Answer (score 0):

hey guys I got the solution. But even I didn't understand how this worked. So, what I did is while coping my command from one method to another method I accidently left the 2 extra slashes on my String command and executed it. And it worked.
Actual Command : `String command = "powershell.exe Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter \"DriveLetter='H:'\" | Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{IndexingEnabled=$False}`" It was not working.

Command which worked : `String command = "powershell.exe Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Filter \\\"DriveLetter='H:'\\\" | Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{IndexingEnabled=$False}`"
I still not able to understand how it worked. because in actual PowerShell command it shouldn't have that back slash before and after DriveLetter.

Comment: You'd have probably saved yourself a lot of time had you used an array as more than one person suggested

Comment: no @g00se i haven't tried array but will try and update the group.